# Windows XP used as server

Tags: networking, windows-xp

Forking [question "running Samba Active Directory Server on Windows desktop (for developing"](https://serverfault.com/questions/168243/running-samba-active-directory-server-on-windows-desktop-for-developing)

I could never understand Windows XP 10-connections limit (added later - in MS licensing), i.e. restrictions in using Windows XP Pro as server.
See [my "Server vs. workstation file server"  question/discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/3ef329e3-fe4f-4ab8-abcb-63cedf52c618#d24ee1b9-0474-4846-b884-384ee7780287).

For ex., http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-remove-the-concurrent-connections-limit-in-windows-xp.html tells: 
"XP introduced the limiting of the number of possible TCP connection attempts to ten per second"...

Really, it is the limit only on attempts per user? per user and  per second? leading to quite ethical thousands connections in production? or ethical hundreds in small developing shop? or dozens connections being sufficient for one developing machine?

Comment: Even with a tweak to bypass the connection limit, you won't be able to install a DC, run Active Directory or GPO, or things like WSUS.  If you're looking to get away from Windows server licensing there are plenty of non-MS alternatives that will be easier and more feature-rich than hacking up XP, which at the end of the day will still not be a Server OS.

Comment: I am really pissed off and tired that any questions of developing on MS platform end up with accusations in conspiracy. Did I want in getting away, I would not discuss it!

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with ethics -- only with attempting to minimize the pain in your ass by convincing you not to run it this way.

Comment: I do not need GPO or WSUS or MS-DC/MS-AD for developing machine. 
Do you mean under "non-MS alternatives" as synonym of "non-Windows-installable". I.e. , on order to develop MS technologies I should get away from Windows?

Comment: For ex., developing against MS SQL Server Enterprise Ed, (requiring Windows Server) is possible with MS SQL Server Developer Ed. installable on non-server Windows.

Comment: No, the Non-MS suggestion applies to features in a DC/server such as the ones you list above that you just can't get with the workstation OS.  For development purposes you can certainly install MS SQL on an XP workstation as in your example.  But usually this wouldn't require > 10 concurrent connections -- if several people will be developing against it they could all have their own copy of SQL express.  If the intent is load testing, you'd want to model the production circumstances (ideally the same hardware and production/server OS) as closely as possible.

Comment: As this site is for professionals I suggest you start acting like a professional and use an appropriate OS for the given task. Trying to use a workstation OS where a server OS is called for is about as unprofessional as it can get and therefore off topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP connection attempts means how many SYN requests (half-open connections) you can have.  There is no limit on TCP established connections.  This was put in to slow down the BOTNETS because you need many more zombies to initiate a DDoS attack.

Comment: I agree! Otherwise it would not have been documented how to overcome this limit

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: the question is in understding the definitions of terms used in MS licensing

Comment: as explained in the technet forum the 10 connection hard limit is on any file, print, named pipe, or mail slot session.  The TCP thing introduced in SP2 is a different limitation.