# OpenLDAP IP socket backend?

Tags: openldap, socket

I see that OpenLDAP has a backend for Unix sockets, but can it be used with IP sockets? or does an IP-socket backend exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, read too fast. Backend.

Don't know if an IP backend exist, but you can always use a tool like `socat` to forward the unix socket over TCP.

Answer (score -5):

From answers in

- https://serverfault.com/questions/168183/open-source-alternatives-to-ms-ad-features-but-installable-on-ms-windows-close
- [running Samba Active Directory Server on Windows desktop (for developing)](https://serverfault.com/questions/168243/running-samba-active-directory-server-on-windows-desktop-for-developing)

I understood that it cannot be because open source developers do not want them to be installable on WIndows also

Comment: -1, You misunderstood that. Windows has specific licensing for network services hosted on it. Samba would violate those license agreements, so it's really not possible to run it on Windows. Microsoft (by way of licensing) prevents Samba on Windows; it has nothing to do with open source programmers. Further; Samba has nothing to do with OpenLDAP backends.

Comment: Samba is a free software alternative to Windows.  As you are using Samba, you certainly do not want to bother with a complicated Windows, with complicated licences...